# d3: apply class to new nodes only in force-directed graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js, d3-force-directed

I have a dynamic simulation with a force-directed graph.

I would like to achieve that all new nodes appear in a certain color, while existing nodes have all the same other color (nodes identified by id).

On each iteration (so I thought), I would apply a class to existing nodes, and set new nodes only to a `new-node` class in the "enter" selection:

```
  restart() {
    // Update and restart the simulation.        
    node = node.data(nodes);
    // Remove all old nodes
    node.exit().remove();
    // Apply class "existing-node" to all existing nodes
    node.attr("class","existing");
    // Apply to all new nodes (enter selection)
    node = node
           .enter()
           .append("circle")
           .attr("r", rad)
           .attr("class", "new-node")
```

Comment: You should use different variables for the enter and the update selections. Right now, you are overwriting `node`. Use `nodeEnter = node.enter().append("circle").etc...`.

Comment: hmmm...that sounds like a good path to look at @GerardoFurtado. I'll see if I can refactor that. Thanks!

Comment: indeed...for the records: this code is just fine. I had an issue elsewhere in my code which was preventing expected behavior. Thanks @GerardoFurtado